# Why is time difference zero, even if I am contacting servers in two different time zones?

Tags: c, datetime, tcpclient, remote-server

I wrote a TCP Client to contact two NIST servers and get the difference between both the times. I have created two sockets for contacting both the servers, then using unixepoch, converted them to system time. While I expected thousands of seconds as difference in output, I am getting the difference as 0 or a few seconds. I couldn't figure out error in my code even after working on it whole day.

```
char    *host = "129.6.15.29";  /* Maryland NIST server */
char    *host1="216.228.192.69"; /*Oregon NIST server*/
char    *service = "time";  /* default service name     */
time_t  now1,now2;          /* 32-bit integer to hold time  */ 
int s1,s2, n1,n2;           /* socket descriptor, read count*/
    double diff_t;

switch (argc) {
case 1:
    host = "129.6.15.29";
    host1="216.228.192.69";
    break;
case 4:
    service = argv[3];
case 3:
    host = argv[1];
    host1= argv[2];
    break;
default:
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: TCPTime [host [port]]\n");
    exit(1);
} 

s1 = connectTCP(host, service);
s2= connectTCP1(host1,service);
(void) write(s1, MSG, strlen(MSG));
(void) write(s2,MSG, strlen(MSG));
/* Read the time */

n1 = read(s1, (char *)&now1, sizeof(now1));
n2 = read(s2, (char *)&now2, sizeof(now2));
if (n1 < 0|| n2<0 )
    errexit("read failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
now1 = ntohl((unsigned long)now1);  /* put in host order    */
now1 -= UNIXEPOCH;      /* convert UCT to UNIX epoch    */
now2 = ntohl((unsigned long)now2);  /* put in host order    */
now2 -= UNIXEPOCH;      /* convert UCT to UNIX epoch    */
printf("%s", ctime(&now1));
printf("%s", ctime(&now2));
diff_t=difftime(now1,now2);
printf("difference between times:%f",diff_t);
exit(0);
```

Please let me know if my approach is right. 
Thanks for taking time to analyze and answer my question.

Here is the sample output:

Fri Oct  7 19:34:59 2016

Fri Oct  7 19:34:58 2016

difference between times:1.000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [time protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Protocol) (which you appear to be using), the server returns the number of seconds since January 1, 1900, midnight UTC (not midnight local time or any other time zone).  Note that this measures from a specific moment, and the amount of time that has passed since then is the same regardless of what timezone you're in.  Thus, the servers will return (almost) the same values at the same time regardless of what timezones they are in.

Comment: Got the point. But how can I implement it so that I can get correct time difference?

Comment: If the servers are only returning time in a resolution of seconds, you can't do anything more than you are doing. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Trying to contact two servers from different timezones to display their local time and difference between both the time zones

Comment: @ZealousCoder: Well the time protocol doesn't return local time.  You'll need to either know ahead of time what timezones the servers are in or else use a different protocol.

Comment: I know that the servers are in Maryland and Oregon, as I mentioned in the question. I am still trying on ways to do that. But, thanks for the answer. I wasn't able to figure out why it was returning 0 seconds always. And, I'd be grateful if you can shed some light on ways to get the time difference (any predefined functions perhaps?).

Answer (score -2):

ctime returns a time_t value, which is an integer of seconds.

So your result can only be 0 seconds, 1 second, 2 seconds, and so on.

There will not be thousands of seconds difference, as both servers return the universal time, not the local time of each server.